# how to print out dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

normally using jupyternotes I can import pandas make my dataframe and export to csv.

I'm trying to automate this reoccurring query with a python script. I can't figure out how to test my script because I cant print out the df to screen. In jupyternotes I just need to type out the df name in any cell and it will display.

here what I'm doing

```
import pandas as pd
def run_agg_query(db):
    df1 = pd.read_sql( "select some query",conn)
    display(df1)
```

but I cant get the df to display.

Comment: Will `print(df1)` not work? or you may need `from IPython.display import display` ? Also, are you getting any error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turns out `print(df)` works just fine it just took a long time to render due to the size of the table. I tried the suggestions above but had strange errors, eventually this worked `print(df['colName'])` which lead me to the above... sometimes the solution is the obvious one *facepalm.

Answer (score 7):

I think printing the dataframe as a string should do the job for you. Something like this might work -

```
print(df.to_string())
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
print("data frame is:\n{}".format(data_pandas))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")

pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

print(df)
```